# ORA-00742: Log read detects lost write in thread 1 sequence 424 block 78120

Tags: oracle

Thanking in advance I ask for help in resolving an issue with Oracle database starting.
Database was working correctly before linux machine reboot, but after reboot through `reboot` terminal command it could not start correctly.
To resolve this issue I've tried:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> startup force
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 2147482944 bytes
Fixed Size                  9137472 bytes
Variable Size             520093696 bytes
Database Buffers         1610612736 bytes
Redo Buffers                7639040 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-01113: file 1 needs media recovery
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/u02/oradata/CDB1/system01.dbf'


SQL> recover datafile '/u02/oradata/CDB1/system01.dbf'
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-00742: Log read detects lost write in thread 1 sequence 424 block 78120
ORA-00312: online log 1 thread 1: '/u02/oradata/CDB1/redo01.log'
```

What steps could I perform to get my database working correctly?

*OS: Oracle Linux 7.6, DBMS: Oracle DB 19c*

Updated. Additional tries, that did not help, but made things worse. I think, it was possible to recover the db somehow using redo01.log.

```
SQL> RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL CANCEL USING BACKUP CONTROLFILE;
ORA-00279: change 7741502 generated at 05/24/2019 11:21:47 needed for thread 1
ORA-00289: suggestion :
/u01/app/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/arch1_423_1007742121.dbf
ORA-00280: change 7741502 for thread 1 is in sequence #423


Specify log: {<RET>=suggested | filename | AUTO | CANCEL}
auto
ORA-00308: cannot open archived log
'/u01/app/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/arch1_423_1007742121.dbf'
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 7


ORA-00308: cannot open archived log
'/u01/app/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/arch1_423_1007742121.dbf'
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 7


ORA-01547: warning: RECOVER succeeded but OPEN RESETLOGS would get error below
ORA-01194: file 1 needs more recovery to be consistent
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/u02/oradata/CDB1/system01.dbf'

SQL> Alter database open;
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01589: must use RESETLOGS or NORESETLOGS option for database open

SQL> Alter database open restlogs;
alter database open resetlogs
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kcbzib_kcrsds_1], [], [], [], [],
[], [], [], [], [], [], []
Process ID: 13270
Session ID: 4 Serial number: 28040

SQL> startup
SP2-0642: SQL*Plus internal error state 2133, context 3114:0:0
Unsafe to proceed
ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE

SQL> quit

sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 2147482944 bytes
Fixed Size                  9137472 bytes
Variable Size             520093696 bytes
Database Buffers         1610612736 bytes
Redo Buffers                7639040 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 14122
Session ID: 462 Serial number: 58943
```

During these tries I've broken something, because of `ORA-03113`

Comment: How did you shutdown?  Did you call Oracle Support yet?

Comment: Shutdown immediate command have been used. This database is for learning, so there's no ability to call Oracle Support.

Comment: I believe the "Ora-600" makes this question "too localized" for this site.